# Where are saved folder custom display settings such as "Group by > Date modified"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, desktop, desktop.ini

I right-clicked in a folder `D:\Test\ABC` and selected "Group by > Date modified", this is really useful for some specific folders, see screenshot below.

Out of curiosity, **where is saved the setting that I want `D:\Test\ABC` to be always displayed like this?** (and not other folders).

I initially thought there would be a hidden `desktop.ini` file  (hidden with *Hide protected operating system files* Folder options) that would contain this display setting, but there is no `desktop.ini` in this folder.

**Where is saved this custom display setting?**

Can such things be set up manually with a `desktop.ini` file?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Can such things be set up manually with a `desktop.ini` file?

No. Grouping is saved in the registry, not a `desktop.ini` file.

Individual folder view settings are remembered if everything is working properly. So once you set the grouping in `D:\Test\ABC`, it should be remembered.

A preferred view layout can also be set as a custom template for the common *FolderTypes* ( Generic/Documents/Music/etc. ) by executing **Apply to Folders** from an **Explorer** window displaying the custom layout.

[image]